# mybatis-ehcache exception after org.ehcache 3.10.8 update

Tags: migration, ehcache-3, ehcache-2

I am getting Exception in org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheCache class after I update net.sf.ehcache version 2.10.9.2 to org.ehcache version 3.10.8.

After referring document from mybatis.org website I know latest mybatis-ehcache version 1.2.3 needs net.sf.ehcache version 2.10.9.2.

My application in spring framework version 5.x. Not the spring boot application.

How to resolve this issue in xml configuration? Is there any way to use org.ehcache 3.x with mybatis-ehcache?